# list media files images and videos of a specific folder

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gallery

Please suggest me a full example or code, list all media like images and videos in a specific folder with share and delete option in grid view. I want this activity when clicking on the navigation button. please add extra like image open and videos play options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**use this class to get all image and videos from a  specific folder**

```
public class ListImage{
// SDCard Path
//choose your path for me i choose sdcard
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Your Folder Name/Path";
private ArrayList<ImageModel> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

// Constructor
public ListImage() {

}

public ArrayList<ImageModel> getPlayList() {

    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()) != null) {
        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
                imageModel .setaName(file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                imageModel .setaPath(file.getPath());

                imageList.add(imageModel);
            }
        }
    }
    return imageList;
}
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".JPG") || name.endsWith(".mp4") || name.endsWith(".MP4")); // add more conditions here
    }
   }
  }
```

**ImageModel**

```
public class ImageModel{
String aPath;
String aName;

public String getaPath() {
    return aPath;
}
public void setaPath(String aPath) {
    this.aPath = aPath;
}
public String getaName() {
    return aName;
}
public void setaName(String aName) {
    this.aName = aName;
 }

}
```

**In your activity/fragment**

```
private ArrayList<ImageModel> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();

ListImage listImage=new ListImage();
this.imagesList = listImage.getPlayList();
```

**update :**

**delete file**

in your adapter delete button click

```
 holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Your Folder Name/Path" + listImage.getaName() + ".jpg";
                            File file= new File(path);
                            if (file.exists()) {
                                if (file.delete()) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(context, "File deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    viewUpdate(position);
                                    fragment.loadData();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "file not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                          }
```

---

```
 public void viewUpdate(int position){
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
}
```

---

also add these permissions in manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: can we use this to get item from private folder? do you have any working example? I mean full code.

Comment: you mean hidden folder?

Comment: yes hidden folder, those are not visible in memory. can you post full code?

Comment: for hiddn folder add " ."  in front of  the path    String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.Your Folder Name";

Comment: Thanks for Replay. Please give me the full code with share and delete options.